# Creating list of files of every subfolders in folders bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem with creating a list of files with template *.cbf in any subfolders of every folders.

I wrote the script in Shell. But it always exit with "no such file or directory".

The structure of path is following /dir/*/*/*.cbf

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
input_dir=$1 
for i in `ls $input_dir/*/*/*_00001.cbf`; do 
    cbf=$(readlink -e $i)
    cbf_fn=$(basename $cbf)
    cbf_path=$(dirname $cbf)
    cbf_path_p2=$(basename $cbf_path)
    cbf_path_p1=$(basename $(dirname $cbf_path))
    find `$input_dir/$cbf_path_p1/$cbf_path_p2` -name "*.cbf" -print > files.lst
done
```

Comment: The find command should do all this for you without the need for a script?

Comment: Why not just `find $input_dir -type f -name "*.cbf"`?

Comment: I have a great amount of folders, that I should prepare in this way. There are more then 1000 folders in which you can find more than 5 subfolders

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that the directory will probably not exist. I'll go through your code:

Suppose your `input_dir` is `/hoppa` and your link is `/hoppa/1/2/a_00001.cbf`. `/hoppa/1/2/a_00001.cbf` is a link that point to `/level1/level2/level3/filename.ext`

```
for i in `ls $input_dir/*/*/*_00001.cbf`; do
```

It is in general a bad idea to process the output of `ls`. Also, for those who once did Fortran (punch-card, ah those days...), `i` suggests an integer. `f` or `file` would probably a better choice. So, assuming that your input-dir does not contain spaces,

```
for file in $input_dir/*/*/*_00001.cbf ; do
    cbf=$(readlink -e $i)
```

(those who sugested `find` probably missed the `readlink`)

```
    cbf_fn=$(basename $cbf)      # cbf_fn=filename.ext
    cbf_path=$(dirname $cbf)     # cbf_path=/level1/level2/level3
    cbf_path_p2=$(basename $cbf_path)
                                 # cbf_path_p2=level3
    cbf_path_p1=$(basename $(dirname $cbf_path))
                                 # cbf_path_p1=level2
    find `$input_dir/$cbf_path_p1/$cbf_path_p2` -name "*.cbf" -print > files.lst
```

So the find will look in `/hoppa/level2/level3`, a directory which may not exist.

```
done
```

Comment: I changed it but unfortunately it doesn't work yet. And I really can't understand what the reason is now:

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash
input_dir=$1
output_dir=$2
for file in $input_dir/*/*/*_00001.cbf ; do #/level1/level2/level3/filename.ext
    cbf=$(readlink -e $file)
    cbf_fn=$(basename $cbf)      # cbf_fn=filename.ext
    cbf_path=$(dirname $cbf)     # cbf_path=/level1/level2/level3
    cbf_path_p2=$(basename $cbf_path) # cbf_path_p2=level3
    cbf_path_p1=$(basename $(dirname $cbf_path)) # 
    cbf_path_p1=level2              
    find `$cbf_path` -type f -name "*.cbf" -print > `$output_dir/files.lst`
done`

Comment: From your first script, I assumed that your `*._00001.cbf` might be links. Is that a correct assumption? Add a small part of `ls -l $input_dir/*/*/*_00001.cbf` to your question as example (`head -5`). Are the target files also called `*.cbf`? Instead of the comments, try `echo $cbf_path` and all the other variables, so you can see them. Are they what you expect them to be?